# I'm not able to input my file in Python (on a Mac)

Tags: python

I have a document called `workbook1.txt` on my desktop and I'm not able to open it in python on a Mac

```
    i = open('C:/Users/rrmenon/Desktop/workbook1.txt', 'r')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    i=open('C/Users/rrmenon/Desktop/workbook1.txt', 'r')
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
    'C/Users/rrmenon/Desktop/workbook1.txt'
```

Comment: Try specifying the path as: `r'C:\Users\rrmenon\Desktop\workbook1.txt'`.

Comment: In window the path's folders is seperated by `folder1\folder2` not by `folder1/folder2`

Comment: @ChihebNexus: That's true, but `/` works as well. The problem was the missing colon (`:`) after the drive letter.

Comment: Oh yes! i didn't saw it the first time. Thnaks.

Comment: Thanks I tried i = open('C:/Users/rrmenon/Desktop/workbook1.txt', 'r') on my Mac and still getting same response- thx

Comment: **The root folder on Mac OS *isnt* `C:/`, but instead just `/`**. Goto finders and find out the CORRECT path. **What you have is a Windows path**

Comment: Perfect thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The root folder on Mac OS isn't `C:/`, but instead just `/`. Goto Finders and find out the CORRECT path to your file. What you currently have is a Windows path.

Alternatively, you can use the os module to expand the path:

```
import os.path
i = open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~rrenon'), 'Desktop/workbook1.txt'), 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

on mac or *nix OS you can import from desktop using 
i = open('~/Desktop/workbook1.txt', 'r')